# How to return the data from the postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return a function with the table field and values

I have a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION books(
    id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        id integer,        
        title text,        
        type text
    )
    LANGUAGE 'sql'    
AS $BODY$

WITH RECURSIVE chain(id, seq) AS (
        SELECT s.id, s.sequence
        FROM product s
        WHERE s.id = $1        
        UNION ALL
        SELECT s.id, s.sequence
        FROM product s, chain t
        WHERE s.id = t.id       
        )
        select * from chain     
$BODY$;
```

My query is currently returning like the following

```
1, book title1, new
2, book title2, new
3, book title3, old
```

I was hoping to return something like

```
id: 1, title: book title1, type: new
id: 2, title: book title2, type: new
id: 3, title: book title3, type: old
```

so I have the key to map the value in the api side.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks, my actual select statement after recursive is similar like:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, cu.name
FROM customer cu, book b
WHERE cu.id = b.id
UNION
(
SELECT c.id, c.title, f.cost
FROM chain c, foo f
WHERE c.id = f.id
)
```

How do I use `row_to_json` to covert them?

Comment: There is [`json_build_object()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to convert the row to json:

```
    select row_to_json(c)
    from chain c
```

Comment: You would just use `row_to_json()` on each subquery.